# I think the cause of my "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value" is not what Xcode is telling me

Tags: swift, xcode

I am getting the ***fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value*** error message, with Xcode highlighting the following code:

```
        shuffledQuestions = GKRandomSource.sharedRandom().arrayByShufflingObjectsInArray(allEntries as [AnyObject])
```

However, I suspect the real problem lies with my approach in this code:

```
func LoadAllQuestionsAndAnswers()
{

    if (lastchosentopic == 1)
    {

    let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("Entertainment", ofType: "json")
    let jsonData : NSData = NSData(contentsOfFile: path!)!
    allEntries = (try! NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(jsonData, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers)) as! NSArray
    //println(allEntries)

    }else{

        if (lastchosentopic == 2)
        {

            let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("General", ofType: "json")
            let jsonData : NSData = NSData(contentsOfFile: path!)!
            allEntries = (try! NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(jsonData, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers)) as! NSArray
            //println(allEntries)

        }else{

            if (lastchosentopic == 3)
            {

                let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("Geography", ofType: "json")
                let jsonData : NSData = NSData(contentsOfFile: path!)!
                allEntries = (try! NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(jsonData, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers)) as! NSArray
                //println(allEntries)

            }else{

                if (lastchosentopic == 4)
                {

                    let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("History", ofType: "json")
                    let jsonData : NSData = NSData(contentsOfFile: path!)!
                    allEntries = (try! NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(jsonData, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers)) as! NSArray
                    //println(allEntries)

                }else{

                    if (lastchosentopic == 5)
                    {

                        let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("Politics", ofType: "json")
                        let jsonData : NSData = NSData(contentsOfFile: path!)!
                        allEntries = (try! NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(jsonData, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers)) as! NSArray
                        //println(allEntries)

                    }else{

                        if (lastchosentopic == 6)
                        {

                            let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("Sport", ofType: "json")
                            let jsonData : NSData = NSData(contentsOfFile: path!)!
                            allEntries = (try! NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(jsonData, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers)) as! NSArray
                            //println(allEntries)

                        }else{

                            if (lastchosentopic == 7)
                            {

                                let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("Random", ofType: "json")
                                let jsonData : NSData = NSData(contentsOfFile: path!)!
                                allEntries = (try! NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(jsonData, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers)) as! NSArray
                                //println(allEntries)

                            }else{

                                if (lastchosentopic == 0)
                                {

                                    if #available(iOS 8.0, *) {
                                        let Alert = UIAlertController(title: "Missing topic?", message: "Sorry, but the app has not registered your selection of topic!", preferredStyle: .Alert)

                                        let DismissButton = UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .Cancel, handler: {(alert: UIAlertAction!) -> Void in})

                                        Alert.addAction(DismissButton)

                                        self.presentViewController(Alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

                                    }else{

                                        let alert = UIAlertView()
                                        alert.title = "Missing topic?"
                                        alert.message = "Sorry, but the app has not registered your selection of topic!"
                                        alert.addButtonWithTitle("Ok")
                                        alert.show()


                                    }}}}}}}}}}
```

I suspect this is the case because my LoadAllQuestionsAndAnswers() function runs prior to the code that Xcode is highlighting as causing the error. However, if I change the code I suspect to be causing the problem to:

```
func LoadAllQuestionsAndAnswers()
{
    let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("content", ofType: "json")
    let jsonData : NSData = NSData(contentsOfFile: path!)!
    allEntries = (try! NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(jsonData, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers)) as! NSArray
    //println(allEntries)

}
```

... I no longer have the problem.

If it helps, I've declared the following variables :

```
var score :Int! = 0
var bestscore :Int!
var totalquestionsasked :Int! = 0
var percentagecorrect :Int! = 0
var accumulatedquestionsasked :Int! = 0

var allEntries : NSArray!

var shuffledQuestions: [AnyObject]!
var nextQuestion = -1

var lastchosenchallenge :Int! = 0
var lastchosentopic :Int! = 0

var currentCorrectAnswerIndex : Int = 0
var answertext:String?

var audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer()
```

I'm running Xcode 7.3.1. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: That indentation is pretty ugly...you might want to learn about Switch statements: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/ControlFlow.html

Comment: You're also force unwrapping everything which is...not recommended.

Comment: It looks as if you need to do quite bit more reading about programming best practices and Swift optionals.  Nested IF statements like that can get very confusing.

Comment: Yeah, I'm only new to programming. Teaching myself in my spare time and obviously have a long way to go. :(

Comment: As peejweej said, look into the switch statement and convert all those IFs to one switch.  As for your error, your allEntries variable is probably nil at the time that line is ran.  But you would have to set a breakpoint to be sure.

Answer (score 2):

I've simplified your code and commented it up to show you a simpler way of accomplishing your goals.

Note that I've removed nearly all of the "!" operators which means less force unwrapping of Optional and less implicitly unwrapped Optional. This means errors are checked and handled properly as they happen. Unwrapping Optional values without checking is the source of many runtime crashes. Try to avoid this!

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

// Names of topics, including None for no topic
//
// Note that the raw value of the enum is String, 
// the raw value for the names are automatically provided
enum Topic: String {
  case None, Entertainment, General, Geography, History, Politics, Sport, Random
}

// Optional Array because the entries might not be loaded
var allEntries : NSArray?

// Type is an enum because it makes handling the values much simpler
var lastchosentopic:Topic = .None

// DRY (Do not Repeat Yourself) Principle, put repeated code into a function
//
// Loads an Array with data, if it fails to load the optional is unset
func load(path path:String) -> NSArray? {
  // guard statements neaten up code and let you exit early
  // Note that we can use two lets and combine them into one with a comma
  guard let
    path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource(path, ofType: "json"),
    jsonData : NSData = NSData(contentsOfFile: path) else { return nil }

  return (try? NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(jsonData, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers)) as? NSArray
}

// The main function of interest, loads allEntries based on lastchosentopic
func LoadAllQuestionsAndAnswers()
{
  // Fail early if there is no topic
  guard lastchosentopic != .None else {
    guard #available(iOS 8.0, *) else {
      let alert = UIAlertView()
      alert.title = "Missing topic?"
      alert.message = "Sorry, but the app has not registered your selection of topic!"
      alert.addButtonWithTitle("Ok")
      alert.show()
      return
    }
    let Alert = UIAlertController(title: "Missing topic?", message: "Sorry, but the app has not registered your selection of topic!", preferredStyle: .Alert)
    let DismissButton = UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .Cancel, handler: {(alert: UIAlertAction!) -> Void in})
    Alert.addAction(DismissButton)
    self.presentViewController(Alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    return
  }

  // load the topic!
  allEntries = load(path:lastchosentopic.rawValue)
}
```

Your `shuffledQuestions` variable will be used like this:

```
var shuffledQuestions: NSArray?

if let allEntries = allEntries as? [AnyObject] {
  shuffledQuestions = GKRandomSource.sharedRandom().arrayByShufflingObjectsInArray(allEntries)
}
```

One more note: You don't seem to need `NSArray` here so you might want to replace it with `[AnyObject]`. Overall, sticking to the Swift types tends to produce less surprises.

Comment: UIAlertView is depreciated. UIAlertController should be used instead.

Comment: That was out of the scope of the question so I didn't bother addressing it but thanks for mentioning that.

Answer (score 0):

As SKError** code is Int,

In Switch block, Please add Default statement. It will work like charm.
var errorMsg = ""

switch error.code {

case .unknown: errorMsg = "Unknown error. Please contact support”

case .clientInvalid: errorMsg = "Not allowed to make the payment"

case .paymentCancelled: errorMsg = "The purchase was cancelled"

case .paymentInvalid: errorMsg = "The purchase identifier was invalid"

case .paymentNotAllowed: errorMsg = "The device is not allowed to make the payment"

case .storeProductNotAvailable: errorMsg = "The product is not available in the current storefront"

case .cloudServicePermissionDenied: errorMsg = "Access to cloud service information is not allowed"

case .cloudServiceNetworkConnectionFailed: errorMsg = "Could not connect to the network"

case .cloudServiceRevoked: errorMsg = "User has revoked permission to use this cloud service"

default:

break

}